# Can sort the Excel tables in multi-thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel

My codes as follow:

```
Parallel.ForEach(listSheets, (xlWorkSheet1) =>
{
  //  Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)excelbk.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
  xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet1.Cells[xlWorkSheet1.Rows.Count, 1];
  lock (xlRange)
  {
     //   nRows = (long)xlRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
     nRows = xlWorkSheet1.UsedRange.Cells.Rows.Count;
     xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet1.Rows["5:" + nRows, Type.Missing];
     xlRange.Sort(xlRange.Columns[clnum1, Type.Missing], 
                  Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                  xlRange.Columns[clnum2, Type.Missing], 
                  Type.Missing, 
                  Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                  Type.Missing, 
                  Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                  Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo, 
                  Type.Missing, 
                  Type.Missing,
                  Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,
                  Excel.XlSortMethod.xlStroke,
                  Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortTextAsNumbers,
                  Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
                  Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);

     Console.WriteLine("Sheet{0} have been sorted", xlWorkSheet1.Name);
  }
}
```

listSheets is defined as a List,and when i debug it,it shows error that the COM exception that problem have been run yet.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Application is busy (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED 0x80010001) Call was rejected by callee (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER 0x8001010A)

Comment: What is the details of the error?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error message? Does the sort work by itself (without the parallel part) ?

Comment: Try to use solution suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908397/c-sharp-excel-beforesave-thread

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 
Application is busy (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED 0x80010001)
Call was rejected by callee (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER 0x8001010A)

Comment: @Nagg I think is it that excel com can support multi-thread to Sort the tabs? Would covert the excel to .net's datatable.maybe it works?

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not support multi-threaded interop calls. Internally, it is multi-threaded. For instance, you can enable multi-threaded recalculations in the options page, for a significant performance boost. However, you cannot peform multi-threaded interop, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

As code4life says: Excel does not support multi-threaded interop calls.
And since Excel's Sort method is already multi-threaded in the latest versions there is no point in trying to multi-thread something thats already multi-threaded.